# SSIS Flat File destination - exported column is rounded to the nearest tenth

Tags: excel, ssis, flatfiledestination

I am using Flat File destination from the SSIS 2010 toolbox. On exporting a column of length 16, the csv flat file shows it in scientific notation (8.05E+15) and on formula bar it is displaying 8046909522611690 where as the original value is 8046909522611695. If I open the CSV in notepad, the value is 8046909522611695. Is there a way to display the value correctly(not in scientific notation and without rounding) on opening the exported flat file using excel.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly it feels more like an Excel question than and SSIS question.

Comment: Don't view it in Excel. View it in notepad. Excel messes with your mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-Click on the column in excel where you require the data to be present in full, and click on 'Format cells..' option. Under 'Category' chose 'Text' and click on 'Ok'. As Zane pointed out the problem you seem to have is with veiewing the content in excel and not the SSIS output itself. This formatting should take care of it.